# manipulate data before binding c# windows phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I want to manipulate data from my database before converting it to list and binding a long list selector to it
i have the following code which gets the required data from my database

```
var tdr =
  from p in ctx.Transactions
  join c in ctx.Type on p.Type equals c.Id
  where p.Date > DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1 * ra) && c.Type1.Equals(ty)
  orderby p.Date descending
  select new { Id = p.Id
             , amont = p.Amont
             , type = p.Type
             , des = p.Des
             , dated =p.Date
             , Aid=p.Acc 
             };
```

i want to use a function to change some values before binding it

```
list32.ItemsSource = tdr.ToList();
```

i tried changing the query to something like this but it didn't work

```
select new { Id = p.Id
           , amont = p.Amont
           , type = p.Type
           , des = p.Des
           , ***dated =somefunction(p.Date)***
           , Aid=p.Acc };
```

any help is appreciated
Thanks

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What is the error message? What is the datasource(ctx.Transactions) - object collection, EF DataSet...?

Comment: An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.Data.Linq.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' has no supported translation to SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no problem in doing what you want.
Here's an example:

```
void Main()
{
    var i = Enumerable.Range(3,4);


    i.Select (x => new { sq = x*x
                       , cu = MyMethod(x)
                       }            
             );
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public int MyMethod(int anInt){
    return anInt*anInt*anInt;
}
```

This will result in:

```
sq     cu
---------
9      27 
16     64 
25     125 
36     216 
86     432
```

Comment: good to know it should be working but it's not nevertheless--here is the error --An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.Data.Linq.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' has no supported translation to SQL.

Comment: Thank you-after i knew it should work i read the error and got it -- Thanks